# Product Data Scraping Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

The product uploading feature will be automated, so all you need to do is enter a product link through the back-end itself and that then add the product photo and description during the night preferably

Please let us know its possible  in Magento

Comment: Not really a programming questions, but seems like interesting feature. Sure, it's possible, but why don't you pull images as well? :)

Comment: Yes, we need images as well.Please let us know how can do it Magento 
please send us any reference extension link

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the best way to achieve that is to create a csv uploader in the backend like you can find in Mage_ImportExport_Adminhtml_ImportController (the whole module can be source of inspiration). The csv feeds a special table that you create with during your module initialization. At the end, with a cron, at the desired time you check this table for the url and then retrieve the photo and description using curl or something similar.

Side considerations :

- If you have a large amount of products to inject, you will prefer direct sql queries than the slow Magento ORM
- Do not forget to deactivate the indexation during import process
- If you need to update and references are different between your source and your Magento, create a special attribute to be sure to have a link between both
- If you feel more confortable with other framework or language and you need to create a large amount of data, the importation process can be done with any language able to interact with mysql.